# Pointless data repetition in STEP file

Tags: step, opencascade

In a STEP file I generated with OpenCascade, I can see this:

```
#58 = VERTEX_POINT('',#59);
#59 = CARTESIAN_POINT('',(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5));
#60 = VERTEX_POINT('',#61);
#61 = CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.5,-0.5,-0.5));
#62 = SURFACE_CURVE('',#63,(#67,#79),.PCURVE_S1.);
#63 = LINE('',#64,#65);
#64 = CARTESIAN_POINT('',(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5));
#65 = VECTOR('',#66,1.);
#66 = DIRECTION('',(1.,0.,0.));
#67 = PCURVE('',#68,#73);
```

The repetition of data `#59` and `#64` annoys me a bit.
Seems like this STEP file could be a bit smaller (*particularly if there thousand of vertices*).
And when I edit the file to use `#59` where `#64` is used, it still looks fine.

Is there a good reason to have this duplicated data?
And more important, is there a way to avoid it?

I already tried creating a `TopoDS_Vertex` for each vertex and avoid repeating `TopoDS_Edge`s that connect the same two vertices.
Those edges are then used to create a `TopoDS_Wire`, which in turn is used to create `TopoDS_Face`.
The whole mesh is put together with a `BRepBuilderAPI_Sewing`.

Thanks

Comment: Currently on version `7.1.0`. I know there's more recent versions and that could be the actual cause.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is just a guess!

The two Cartesian points `#59` and `#64` are by chance identical, but different geometric entities are being built upon them. Obviously the surface curve `#62` referring to the line `#63` referring to the Cartesian point `#64` could also refer to point `#59`.

But what should happen, if someone opens the STEP file and wants to modify the coordinates of vertex `#58` which are stored in the Cartesian point `#59`? Should the line `#63` and surface curve `#62` also be modified? Or should they be redefined? Why should modification of vertex `#58` cause a redefinition of another entity that shares only by chance one Cartesian position?

Therefore I guess that your proposal would be some kind of "STEP format compression", but the actual intention is the clean definition of hierarchies of geometric entities.

Comment: I can see your point for potential modification of the data. But a good editor should be able to go around this. Also, the line definition could be simplified by attaching two cartesian points together instead of relying on a vector (vector that is the difference between two cartesian points, which is a different way of data duplication).

Comment: I guess you are right - but why change anything? If minimal file size was the intention of the STEP file format, it would be a binary format anyway!